# [JPA, eclipselink]OneToMany Relationship not fetching the childern

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, eclipselink

i have a problem with an OneToMany relationship. I try to get the List but it does not retrieve anything. Theses are my sources:

This the Main:

```
        public class ModelTest {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

           //Creating 
           {
               StudyEntity st = new StudyEntity();       
               st.setPatientName("Edwin");
               st.setStudy_pk("111");           
               new StudyCRUD().create(st);



               StudyEntity st2 = new StudyEntity();
               st2.setPatientName("Jose");
               st2.setStudy_pk("2333");
               new StudyCRUD().create(st2); // Persist the object in DB



               SeriesEntity se = new SeriesEntity();
               se.setSeries_iuid("44444");
               se.setStudyentity(st);
               new SeriesCRUD().create(se);



               SeriesEntity se2 = new SeriesEntity();
               se2.setStudyentity(st);




               new SeriesCRUD().create(se2); // Persist the object in DB
           }

           //Retrieving
           {
               StudyEntity study = new SeriesCRUD().getStudyEntityByID(1); // Get a Object    by ID 
               System.out.println("Name: "+study.getPatientName());
               System.out.println("Size: "+study.getStudySeries().size());
           }



        }

    }
```

**Result**

> Name: Edwin 
>   Size: 0

Tables info:

**studyentity**

```
       ida, DELETED, MODALITY, PATIENTNAME, SENT, STUDY_DATETIME, STUDY_ID, STUDY_PK<br />
       1, 0, '', 'Edwin', 0, '', '', '111'<br />
       2, 0, '', 'Jose', 0, '', '', '2333'<br />
```

**seriesentity**

```
       ID, SERIES_IUID, SERIES_PK, ida
       1, '', '', 1
       2, '', '', 1
```

The entities tables:

**studyentity**

```
    @Entity @Table(name="studyentity")
    public class StudyEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(name="ida")
    private long id;

    private String patientName;
    private String study_id;

    private String modality;

    @Column(unique=true )
    private String study_pk;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date study_datetime;

    private boolean sent;

    @Column(columnDefinition="boolean default false")
    private boolean deleted;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="studyentity")
    private List<SeriesEntity> studySeries;

    //getters and setters
```

**seriesentity**

```
    @Entity @Table(name="seriesentity")
    public class SeriesEntity implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ida", nullable = false)    
    private StudyEntity studyentity;

    private String series_pk;

    private String series_iuid;

    //Getters and Setters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA does not maintain relationships for you.  Unless you add the seriesEntity instance to the studyEntity's collection, it won't be there unless you force a refresh.  It's better though just to set both sides of bidirectional relationships in your entities when creating them then forcing a database hit to fix it later.